# Select count without join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm using MySQL. I have three tables, and in every table, I have a `time` column.

With a single query I want to count the number of rows that are `between` two given dates.

I have no need with a connection between the tables (although they are related), so `join` is not necessary.

Is it possible?

Failed attempt #1

```
SELECT
  COUNT(a.time),
  COUNT(b.time),
  COUNT(c.time)
FROM
  tbl1 AS a,
  tbl2 AS b,
  tbl3 AS c
WHERE
  a.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55'
AND
  b.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 18:46:55'
AND
  c.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 18:46:55' ;
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that you *do* have a join, and it's a cartesian join, so every row in `a` between your dates is matched with every row in `b` that matches, and every row in `c` matches. If `time` is never `NULL`, you'll get the same count for each, and it will be the number of rows from `a` times the number of rows from `b` times the number of rows from `c`. Whenever you have more than one table in the `FROM` clause, you have a join of some sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it pivoted:

```
SELECT 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  tbl1
         WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55'
                        AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55' ) AS a
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  tbl2
         WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55'
                        AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55' ) AS b
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  tbl3
         WHERE time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55'
                        AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55' ) AS c
;
```

which gives something like

```
  a   b   c
 10   3  14
```

Answer (score 7):

This would probably need to be a UNION query, as in:

```
SELECT 'a'
  , COUNT(a.time)
FROM
  tbl1 AS a
WHERE
  a.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55' 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'b'
  , COUNT(b.time)
FROM
  tbl2 AS b
WHERE
  b.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55' 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'c'
  , COUNT(c.time)
FROM
  tbl3 AS c
WHERE
  c.time BETWEEN '2018-03-07 18:32:55' AND '2018-03-07 20:46:55'
```

The output would look like:

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ col1 ║ col2 ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ a    ║   10 ║
║ b    ║    3 ║
║ c    ║   14 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```